# VSTO Ms-Word addin -i need to show publisher name in Ms-Word addin section. I aready digtaly sign with digicert

Tags: c#, windows, vsto, add-in, word-addins

i need to show publisher name in Ms-Word addin section. I aready digtally sign with **DigiCert**. But i will not able to show publihser name on Ms-Word. eveny i try all posible task but still can't able show the publisher name.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DiXuI.png)
i will try every process.